# Memory leak when I am using Leptonica (lept4j library)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I encounter with memory leak problem when I use Leptonica(class of lept4j library). 
When I call **LeptUtils.convertImageToPix(fi)** function in a for-loop, it goes to 
**OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** exception.

```
for (BufferedImage fi : images) {
    Pix pix = LeptUtils.convertImageToPix(fi); // Memory leak is here
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage2(api, pix);
    String line = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(api).getString(TessAPI1.TRUE);
    pdfContent.add(line);
}
```

I checked another parts of my code and only when it passes through **convertImageToPix(...)** method, PC's using memory increases.

> Below I was trying to use dispose method of LeptUtils. It didn't help.

```
LeptUtils.disposePix(pix)
```

***Do I possible clean memory to avoid this problem? if yes, how can I do it?***

Comment: Getting an `OutOfMemoryError` does not indicate that you have leak, only that you are using a comparatively large amount of memory.  You can increase the amount of heap available via command-line options such as `-Xmx`.  In as much as you appear to be generating *and retaining* an unknown number of potentially large objects, that may be exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I set this value to `-Xmx6096m`. Besides I used bigger value, but an application just was frozen.

Comment: If you are trying to use more memory than the VM can acommodate, and there's no way to make it accommodate more, then your only alternative is to use less.  I haven't enough information to suggest details.